# Is it possible to add two functions together in C++?

Tags: c++, function, addition

I am looking for a way to return the addition of two functions within int main().  Is this possible or do I have to take the long route?

Comment: Can you please put the "long route" code in your question so we are able to understand your specific problem better?

Comment: the long route? In what context are you using these two functions?

Comment: What do you mean with "addition of two functions"?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to your question and reformulate it (preferably with code samples) in order to get a (useful) answer.

Comment: check this out first...  https://stackoverflow.com/q/1430907/7504001

Comment: Alright thanks for the info.  I found what I was looking for, however.  I was trying to add a few string functions together in a variable, but I was having some compiler issues.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int mul(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}

int main()
{
    int result = add(1, 2) + mul(3, 4);
}
```

you mean ?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.  Thank you.  Funny, I was just about to edit this question and say I found a solution but you already answered.  For some reason I kept getting an error every time I stored the sum in a variable.  I just did something like cout << add(1,2) + mul(3,4);.  Idk what I did to fix it but it's working now.